# Passing the previous page title to a custom checkout field in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

With Woocommerce, is it possible to pass the previous page title to a custom checkout fields?

Comment: yes it's possible is there any specific location you want to display the previous tittle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated** - The following code example uses PHP Session to grab the previous page title *(this code example can be extended)*:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'grab_previous_page_title' );
function grab_previous_page_title() {
    session_start();

    // Not on checkout page
    if( ! is_checkout() ) { 
        $_SESSION['previous_page_title'] = wp_title('', false);
    }
}
```

> In checkout page you will be able to get the previous page title using:
>
> ```
> $previous_page_title = $_SESSION['previous_page_title'];
> ```

Then in checkout page we can add this previous page title in a hidden input field:

```
// Checkout: Display a hidden input field with previous page title inside checkout form
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'hidden_input_field_previous_page_title' );
function hidden_input_field_previous_page_title() {

    if( isset($_SESSION['previous_product_title']) ) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="previous_page_title" value="'.$_SESSION['previous_page_title'].'">';
    }
}
```

Then when order is submitted, we save the custom hidden field value as order meta data:

```
// Save the custom hidden field value as order meta data
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_previous_page_title', 22, 2 );
function save_previous_page_title( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['previous_page_title']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_previous_page_title', sanitize_text_field($_POST['previous_page_title']) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: yes it's work for product page title, but I want the previous page title not the product page title, can you please help me in this,

Comment: The above answer is correct except for one part: ``` if( isset($_SESSION['previous_product_title']) ) {
``` Should be: ``` if( isset($_SESSION['previous_page_title']) ) {
```

Comment: @dontgiveajack NO because we save the data from the field that is submitted…